# Vue 2 mutating a data property inside a v-for causes infinite loops / problems

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

Although I could not find in the documentation, it appears that mutating a data array property isn't a good idea, even when it's not being rendered out to the view.

See this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/078v5142/3/

I need to decrement `conditionalSet`. I'm using `pop()` on every v-for loop to check the condition of an index. I can't use a computed property because i need to pass the index.

I can't just copy the `conditionalSet` array either because it needs to be tracked when a condition is set and popped.

This is a greatly simplified problem that I'm facing.

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue.js! I do not like loops, all that much.',
    imageSet: [
     'a','b','c','d','e','f','g', 'h', 'i', 'j'
    ],
    conditionalSet: [1,2]
  },
  methods: {
    doShow(index){
     if(this.someInnerConditionThatsNotRenderedOut()){
       if( index === 1 || index === 4 || index === 5 || index === 6){
         this.conditionalSet.pop(); // <-- this is the problem, but how to I track?
         return true;
       }
     }
     console.log('I should no show index 5 and index 6')
    },
    someInnerConditionThatsNotRenderedOut(){
     return true //comment this out. No error.
     return this.conditionalSet.length > 0
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### The short answer

To cut a long story short, I think you can (and should) use a computed property for displaying the filtered list. I'm not 100% clear what you were trying to achieve in your example, but hopefully this fiddle gives you a pointer: https://jsfiddle.net/dtchqpjd/ If you look at the console when it runs, you'll be able to see how the logic pans out.

#### The longer answer

The problem is really caused by a combination of three things:

- Your `doShow` function has a side-effect.
- That side-effect is related to a data property, which is 'watched' by VueJS.
- That data property is an array, which you need to 'get' in order to modify/pop.

VueJS has a [reactivity system](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html) which watches data and, when it changes, determines the effect this will have on the DOM. This allows it to efficiently update the DOM in response to data changes, without needing to completely re-create the DOM every time something changes.

In this case, VueJS knows the following:

- You get the `conditionalSet` property. You have to do this to call the pop method. But Vue doesn't know what you did with the value returned.
- You change the `conditionalSet` property by calling the pop method.

Because you *get* and *set* the property, VueJS assumes that the result returned by the `doShow` function is stale, and hence re-evaluates it, and then you get an infinite loop. It can't see that you only 'got' it because you wanted to 'pop' it!

When you perform the filtering and modification all within a computed property, you avoid confusing VueJS (and the infinite loop) as it can see that the result is stable and doesn't need to be re-computed. It also happens to be much clearer code since the logic is all in one place. However, your computed property still has a side-effect which, if maybe if I understood more about what you were trying to do, could probably be avoided too.

#### A small illustration

To illustrate what's happening, [here's a slight modification to your fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y0b84Ljn/), where I've taken a separate (unknown to Vue) reference to the array. When I use that reference to call 'pop', you don't get the infinite loop: Vue can still see that we've changed the array, but because we didn't 'get' it, it doesn't assume that the output of the function is now stale. Uncomment the call which just 'gets' the array, and the problem comes back: Vue thinks it needs to re-evaluate the function.

Interestingly, Vue doesn't appear to look at the order of the dependencies: it doesn't matter if you 'get' then 'set', or 'set' then 'get'. It's just the fact that you did both which causes the circular dependency - they get added as dependencies and lead to a re-evaluation on the queue.

Commenting out the `return true` statement avoids the infinite loop simply because it prevents the array from being continually 'popped': once the array has been popped twice, your `someInnerConditionThatsNotRenderedOut` function returns false, and the potential for an infinite loop is cut short.

Comment: Just read your comment on the other answer about needing to keep the <template v-if> - I'll try to update...

Comment: Updated the fiddle. There's still something very wrong with the fact that you feel the need to pop the array during rendering, but I don't know enough about your specific problem to figure out what to do instead. Hope it helps, anyway.

Comment: Ah the crux of it is your beforeMount hook and removing the reactivity. Clever. I will have a rethink to my "real problem" , but what you've illustrated here has solved it. Thank you for your time.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/xbcn6hpw/6/ Simple example of why vue fails with passing parameters into a v-if through a v-for. But I need this functionality...

Answer (score 0):

You just thought hard almost ;)

Imagine one computed method which filters your `imageSet` and returns which result you want and your `v-for` act on it.

Your fiddle with some changes:
https://jsfiddle.net/5dbakawb/

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't remove that <template v-if> component inside the loop. It's actually a placeholder for an advert component. Therefore, it just can't be swapped out like you've done.

Comment: @Simon So, don't remove it :) I did it to make it more simple.